# Linear Transformation on $\mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $W$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and let $T:\mathbb R^6 \to W$ be a linear transformation such that $S = \{Te_2, Te_4, Te_6\}$ spans $W$. Wich one of the following must be true?
>
> - (A) $S$ is a basis of $W$
> - (B) $T(\mathbb R^6) \ne W$
> - (C) $\{Te_1, Te_3, Te_5\}$ spans $W$
> - (D) $\ker T$ contains more than one element

I'm having trouble starting this problem.

Here are my findings so far:

I tried Dimension theorem and found that $\ker(T)$ contains more than three elements so (D) is incorrect.
And taking $\dim(T(\mathbb R^6))=\dim(W)$ we get $T(\mathbb R^6)=W$ so (B) is incorrect.
I think (C) option is correct but still not able to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: What have you done so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for suggestions.I’ll make sure I don’t repeat these mistakes in future.

Comment: @ap21 The question was now reopened. See the edit made to your question to see how you should formulate it in the future. Is the problem solved now or do you need any further assistance?

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for the help. I get the answer but is there any prove for (c) option?

Comment: @ap21 Yes, as I told you (C) is wrong and you can explicitly give $T$ akin to the $T$ in my answer such that all of $Te_1, Te_3$ and $Te_5$ will be dependent while $\dim W = 2$. Think of
$$T = \pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1}$$

Comment: @AlexR  According to ques one option must be correct. So if (c) is wrong then which one must be correct?

Comment: @ap21 As you figured out on your own, it's (D). Note that "more than one" is satisfied since you found $\dim\ker T \ge 3$ and $\dim U > 0$ as an $\mathbb R$ vector space implies that $U$ has an infinite number of elements.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks, I think I've got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a problem is most effectively tackled by looking at each point and asking oneself *How could this become wrong?*. Let me get you started:

Since $W$ is spanned by a set of three vectors, it has dimension at most $3$. Let's thus assume $W = \mathbb R^d$ with $d\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ for the tasks (this will actually be enough).

For (A) to go wrong, $S$ must be linearly dependent. This is the case if our $d$ is smaller than $3$, wich is certainly possible. A concrete example for $d = 2$ would be
$$T = \pmatrix{1&2&3&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&2&3}\\
S = \{Te_2, Te_4, Te_6\} = \{(2,0)^T, (0,1)^T, (0,3)^T\}$$

Is there a way to make (B) wrong?

*and so on...*

I will be happy to provide further help given that you actually show some work. Consider this a "kick-off" ;)

Comment: Thanks for help.I tried Dimension theorem and found that Ker(T) contains more than three elements so (d) is incorrect.And taking dim(T($\mathbb{R}^6$))=dim(W) we get T($\mathbb{R}^6$)=W so (b) is incorrect.I think (c) option is correct but still not able to prove it.Please help!

Comment: @ap21 Very good. Everything is correct. For a counter-example to (C) chose the columns of $T$ such that $e_1, e_3$ and $e_5$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @ap21 If $ker(T)$ contains more than $3$ elements, then it certainly contains more than $1$ element, so shouldn't option d) be correct?

Comment: @Diya You're right, option (D) is true (since $\dim \ker T > 0$). I don't expect the answerer to be around anymore though looking at his rep and last seen...

Comment: @AlexR thanks a lot! I was doing this problem and needed the help :) :)